# Releasing UIImage created with imageWithData

Tags: ios

I have an application that stores images as `NSData` in Core Data.

I load those images on my views when needed using `imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:<...>]`. When I leave the view the memory allocated for that `UIImage` is not deallocated.

I am using ARC and I set my image view to nil on my `viewDidUnload:` method.

Is there anything else I can do about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I leave the view"? Does the view controller get deallocated?

Comment: I mean I pop it from a navigation controller.

Comment: You mean, that you want to remove image from view? Use [imageView removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't expect the data to be deallocated as soon as you leave the view. This is not your responsibility even more when you're using ARC. All those objects will probably go in some autorelease pool which will be drained when iOS decides or have a need to.

Comment: But whenever I reenter the view the image view gets initialized again and since `imageWithData` has no caching I have the same image(s) in memory twice, thrice and so on for as many times I reenter the view. Should I implement memory caching for `imageWithData`?

Comment: You can make caching as long as you have problems without it. I am sure you have a name attribute for every image so the easiest thing is make either a NSMutableDictionary with name for key and UIImage for object or better a NSCache object... Then only take images from the caching object and if they don't exists add them in...